# Where are the top bar links gone?

Tags: support

With the new top bar design I miss the links to Chat, and Meta.

How can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links are now accessible from the Stack Exchange widget on the top left corner. There you will also find links to other sites in the Stack Exchange Network.

[image]